# Unordered list won't align properly inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a NavBar out of images.

The images are inside a list item `li` which is inside an unordered list `ul` which is inside a `div`.

The problem I'm having is that when I make an unordered list displaying inline, it doesn't align to the left of the div like it should, it starts about 40 pixels in. I tried setting `position:absolute;left:0;` on the `ul` but it doesn't make a difference.

`position:absolute;` is supposed to make it align relative to its parent element, but it's not doing that.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zwyjk/1/) displaying the problem.

(The red block is the div, it's red just to show you where the side of the div is so you can see how far off the ul is)

Is there something I'm missing? Why does the image start 40 pixels to the right of where it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

```
#navbar ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Specifically, I believe that it's the padding

Comment: Yes, I was just cleaning up his margin.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the `padding-left` on the `ul`

Comment: @user1938671 I upvoted your answer before commenting. I just wanted to highlight the salient part of your answer for any future reader.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add padding: 0;

```
#navbar ul{
    padding:0;
}
```

Also, 2 things you might want to look into that will cause you similar problems:

1) **Inheritance**

Inheritance is something where if you don't specify certain values, it will simply take the value of the same elements from the parents.

2) **CSS reset**

All browsers have their own default values for certain things. you want to make sure that you reset some of those values, if you want full control. It will likely impact the speed of your website loading minimally.

Comment: I think you should make margin and padding equal to 0. Have you tried that?

Comment: It appears, setting margin-top to 0 fixes the vertical one and padding-left fixes the horizontal one.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` and other lists  have 40px `padding-left` by default, in older IE it is `margin`, so just remove padding and margin.